# Failed to execute child process ''gnome-software'' (No such file or directory)

Tags: gnome

Failed to execute child process ''gnome-software'' (No such file or directory)

Pleases help to solve this

Comment: please [edit] your question to clearly indicate what it was you were trying when this occurred. The exact steps will help understand what your issue is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.